# Django REST Framework: Type Error When Trying To Update Using Nested Serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-viewsets

I am trying to use a nested serializer in Django Rest Framework. I basically want to update my instance in a single shot. When I send my response, it throws an error saying-
save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'. I tried popping "id" but then it just repeats the same error with a different attribute.

Here is my model:

models.py

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

serializers.py

```
from ..models import Language, Lead, Genre, Business
from rest_framework import serializers

class LanguageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = Language
        fields = "__all__"

class LeadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    language_id = LanguageSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = "__all__"



    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        language_ids = [item['id'] for item in validated_data['language_id']]

        for language in instance.language_id.all():
            if language.id not in language_ids:
                language.delete()

        for item in validated_data['language_id']:
            if item.get("id", None) is not None:
                lang = Language.objects.get(id=item["id"])
                lang.save(**item) #This throws an error
            else:
                lang = Language.objects.create(**item)
                instance.language_id.add(lang)

 
        validated_data.pop("language_id")
        validated_data.pop("id")
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: why do you have `id = serializers.IntegerField()` in each serializer? Isn't it included by default?

Comment: @C.K. is right. Try without ```id = serializers.IntegerField()```. Should work. Unless theres a reason you are explicitly defining that field

Comment: Without id = serializers.IntegerField() the id doesn't get passed.

Comment: hi, can you post also the `Lead` model ?